# Sentence Generation: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, nonetype, sentence

i have a code for generating sentences given a word after sentence_start

the code that encountered an error:

```
def generate_sentences(model, n, index_to_word, word_to_index):
    for i in range(n):
        sent = None
        while not sent:
            for i in range(len(arr)):
                sent = generate_sentence(arr[i], model, index_to_word, word_to_index)
                # print (arr[i])
                print_sentence(sent, index_to_word)
        print("\n")
```

here is the called function:

```
def generate_sentence(anot, model, index_to_word, word_to_index, min_length=5):
    # We start the sentence with the start token
    new_sentence = [word_to_index[SENTENCE_START_TOKEN], word_to_index[anot]]
    # Repeat until we get an end token
    while not new_sentence[-1] == word_to_index[SENTENCE_END_TOKEN]:
            next_word_probs = model.predict(new_sentence)[-1]
            samples = np.random.multinomial(1, next_word_probs)
            sampled_word = np.argmax(samples)
            new_sentence.append(sampled_word)
            # Seomtimes we get stuck if the sentence becomes too long, e.g. "........" :(
            # And: We don't want sentences with UNKNOWN_TOKEN's
            if len(new_sentence) > 100 or sampled_word == word_to_index[UNKNOWN_TOKEN]:
                return None
    if len(new_sentence) < min_length:
        return None
    return new_sentence

def print_sentence(s, index_to_word):
    sentence_str = [index_to_word[x] for x in s[1:-1]]
    print(" ".join(sentence_str))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

and here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-b9a0a1f5bd04>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/cerdas/Documents/bil/Code_Latihan/rnn-tutorial-gru-lstm-master/train.py', wdir='C:/Users/cerdas/Documents/bil/Code_Latihan/rnn-tutorial-gru-lstm-master')

  File "C:\Users\cerdas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\cerdas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/cerdas/Documents/bil/Code_Latihan/rnn-tutorial-gru-lstm-master/train.py", line 53, in <module>
    generate_sentences(model, 20, index_to_word, word_to_index)

  File "C:\Users\cerdas\Documents\bil\Code_Latihan\rnn-tutorial-gru-lstm-master\utils.py", line 190, in generate_sentences
    print_sentence(sent, index_to_word)

  File "C:\Users\cerdas\Documents\bil\Code_Latihan\rnn-tutorial-gru-lstm-master\utils.py", line 179, in print_sentence
    sentence_str = [index_to_word[x] for x in s[1:-1]]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

i suspect the error caused by the function `print_sentence(sent, index_to_word)`
i was trying to edit the indentation for exclude the `print_sentence` function from looping.

but the output only read the last element of array `arr`

Comment: If `generate_sentence()` returns `None` then you will get this error because you cannot iterate over a `None` object.  Since you have some criteria built-in where `None` can be returned I suspect that is the case.  You might want to try to capture this error in `print_sentence()` to look at what inputs are generating this behavior so that you can gracefully handle them in the code.

Comment: You deliberately `return None` in some cases in `generate_sentence`. But whatever that function returns, you assign it to `sent`, and then call `print_sentence` with `sent`. And then, whatever you pass to `print_sentence`, it tries to loop over. That’s the problem; the right fix depends on what you wanted to do. Why do you return None, and what do you want to happen when you do it? If you can explain that, it should be easy to implement whatever you explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error message

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

means, is that your line

```
sentence_str = [index_to_word[x] for x in s[1:-1]]
```

is trying to access `index_to_word[x]` and `s[1:-1]` though one of them appear to be  `None`

Seeing that you didn't provide the information what `generate_sentences` is being called with, we can only speculate what causes this.

I would recommend you add an if clause, to make sure you don't try to print a sentence, which is `None`:

```
print_sentence(sent, index_to_word)
```

should be replaced with

```
if sent is not None:
    print_sentence(sent, index_to_word)
```

Comment: `if sent:` is enough. the `is not None` is redundant.

Comment: Quoting PEP8: "Also, beware of writing `if x` when you really mean `if x is not None` -- e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value. The other value might have a type (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!"